# Truncate datespan query from Oracle to C#

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, date, oracle11g

I am a newbie to .net and C#. I have an Oracle query which looks like this->

```
select trunc(mod((sysdate-datestamp)*24*60, 60) ) from tablename
where type = 'xyz';
```

datestamp is of type Date in Oracle table. How do I implement this in my .net mvc code. I am using Entity framework. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where do you have trouble implementing this?

Comment: I am converting a coldfusion application to .net mvc. The above query was in a coldfusion code. The above query is selected as 'difference' which I want to use in my .net code.